# How to inject Repository object in my Domain Entity/Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have few validations to be done for a domain entity which requires DB Call.So i wanted to use my repository object in my domain model.I tried using Dependency injection but it does not do the work,and gives me null

```
public class ObjectX : Base
{
    public IObjectRepository _ObjectRepository;

    public Location(IObjectRepository objRepo)
    {
        this._ObjectRepository= objRepo;
    }
 int someProperty{get; set;}
 
 bool validateProperty()
 {
  bool isValid =_ObjectRepository.ValidateProperty(someProperty);
  return isValid;
 }
```

So here the objRepo is coming null and hence the constructor also assigns null to _ObjectRepository.I have put the <IObjectRepository ,ObjectRepository> in Startup.cs

Is it possible to access the repository object here in domain model ?

Comment: The question for me is why do you want to do this. Why not do this at the service layer?

Comment: I don't think your domain should take a dependency on your repository, but your issue is with how you register the repo in the IoC container since you are getting an instance, but it is null.

Comment: @MasoudSharifi I have a design like this "controller->servicelayer->dataAccessLayer(repositories here) ".there will be a add lot of validations for each objects if I do it in service layer. Should I create specific service layers just for validation purposes.I only need to validate my properties against the database.Nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

With data-centric objects, such as Domain Entities, it is not a common approach to have dependencies injected in the object's constructor. It's not that it's *impossible* to resolve those dependencies from a DI Container, but DI Containers are meant to build up object graphs of components, which tend to be long lived, not data objects, which tend to be short lived. Generally speaking, mixing runtime data and stored dependencies in the same (data) object can lead to [many complications](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/). It comes down to [Nikola’s 1st law of IoC](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/):

> ***Store in IoC container only services. Do not store any entities.***

Instead, a more common approach is to move from [Constructor Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) (as you are doing in your example) to [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/). With Method Injection you can supply an already initialized object with a dependency through its public API, without the need for that object to store its incoming dependency.

In your case, the use of Method Injection would result in the following code:

```cs
public class ObjectX : Base
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
 
    public bool ValidateProperty(IObjectRepository objRepo)
    {
        if (objRepo is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objRepo));
        bool isValid = objRepo.ValidateProperty(someProperty);
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Notice how:

- `ObjectX`'s public API (`ValidateProperty`) accepts the `IObjectRepository` as method argument.
- `ValidateProperty` does use, but not store the incoming dependency.

Note that:

- A method can have both dependencies and runtime data as input arguments.
- This moves the responsibility of supplying the dependency to the consumer of `ObjectX`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added it to your IoC container? You can do it in your startup file,

```cs
services.AddScoped<IObjectRepository, ObjectRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I misunderstood the whole question. Here is what I think.
If you need a Db call to validate around other aggregate (and thats the only case for dbcall in proper domain) You dont inject repository, you inject generilized Event dispatcher And rise domain specific events. dispatcher is injected to method call. You set proper message piping in application layer using proper Domain defined handlers.

You need to set proper event bus in event dispatcher from application layer and inject it via domain method injection. Just Take it from IoC container of app and pass it to domain method.

i will check code in my project later when i get home. cant think strait in the morning

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

here is what i did to inject message system into aggregate

```
public interface IDomainDispatcher
{
   IDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> Bus<TDomainEvent>(TDomainEvent domainEvent) where TDomainEvent : DomainEvent;
}

public interface IDomainEventBus<in TDomainEvent> where TDomainEvent : DomainEvent
{
    Task<bool> Dispatch(TDomainEvent domainEvent);
}

public interface IDomainEventHandler<in TDomainEvent>
{
    IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent> NextHandle {  get; }
    Task<bool> Handle(TDomainEvent domainEvent);
}

class ParralelDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> : IDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> where TDomainEvent : DomainEvent
{
    IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>> events;

    ParralelDomainEventBus(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>> events)
    {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public Task<bool> Dispatch(TDomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        //parallel invoke
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class SequenceDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> : IDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> where TDomainEvent : DomainEvent
{
    IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>> events;

    SequenceDomainEventBus(IEnumerable<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>> events)
    {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public Task<bool> Dispatch(TDomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        //parallel invoke
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public abstract class  SomeDispatcher : IDomainDispatcher
{
    public IDomainEventBus<TDomainEvent> Bus<TDomainEvent>(TDomainEvent domainEvent) where TDomainEvent : DomainEvent
    {
        //reflect on fields and find proper bus return it
        //return new DefaultBus<TDomainEvent>() if not found
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
    private class DefaultBus<T2DomainEvent> : IDomainEventBus<T2DomainEvent> where T2DomainEvent : DomainEvent
    {
        public Task<bool> Dispatch(T2DomainEvent domainEvent)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```